# Time spent focusing on a control WPF

Tags: wpf, focus, controls

I'm working on calculating the time that the user is focusing on a control like SpellCheckTextBox, i just need some help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events of the controls and use a `StopWatch` or some other method of recording the time lapse.